# Finding if the current page is in a Zend Navigation object

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I have more than one `Zend_Navigation` object in my application.  I want to do a test to find out which object holds the page I'm currently on.  I didn't see methods for doing that in the documentation.  Can this be accomplished? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `findById()` function after using some logic very specific to my implementation to determine which navigation object applied to the current request.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no public method to do compare all pages in the container recursively at once.

You may implement your own method iterating all the pages and the subpages in the container (`Zend_Navigation` implements `RecursiveIterator`) and check `$container->isActive()` status or compare container params with the current `$request->getParams();`.